# Is it good to provide a GitHub link to whole source code rather than a snippet in question?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions

I am facing a problem in my code. But I am completely unaware of what part of the code is causing the problem. I can explain in details about what problems I am facing, but not what might be causing it.

In that case, linking the GitHub repository with source code in question is a good practice or can it be seen as a negative point for being less specific and clear. The source code is relatively small and easy to understand.

Comment: No, you can add a *supporting* offsite link but the [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) must be in the question itself. Cutting down to the core problem is part of basic debugging, see e.g. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: See [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/4642212) — in short: no.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm afraid you'll need to spend some more time debugging your application to figure out where the problem is. Questions asking us to find a needle in a haystack generally don't fare well. They get downvoted and are often closed.

Some sites (or more specifically tags within those sites) duplicate such questions to general "how do I debug my application" questions and answers. You could look for those questions and answers yourself if you're not sure how to use a debugger.

If we need to access external resources in order to answer your question that's yet another reason it's likely to be closed as questions need to be self-contained. Links should always be optional.

Comment: In that case, will it be better to ask "How can i find the cause of this problem" type of question rather than "where is the problem and how to solve it"